# how to create an Alert Dialogu in Android without onCliclkListener

Tags: android

I wanted to display an Alert Dialogue inside thread or alternatively such a way that AlertDialogue opens up directly after finding some records in database negative, w/o clicking on any button..
Alert dialogue may contain Few lines and 2-3 buttons..

referred following link and tried on my own but not getting how to create an AlertDialogue without using onClickListener as its working with it(onClickListener) very smoothly:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class jar_layut extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    boolean out=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        { public void run() 
        { 
            try {
                out=first_check_pic_on_device();

                mHandlerMySpace5.post(mUpdateResultsMySpace5);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                mHandlerMySpace5.post(mUpdateResultsMySpace5);
            }

        }
      } ).start();
    }
    private boolean first_check_pic_on_device()
    {
         Context contextMySpace= this;;

        try {
            FileInputStream stream =contextMySpace.openFileInput("prf.png");

                  try {



                      return true;

                  } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                      return false;
                    }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return false;
        }
    }
    final Handler mHandlerMySpace5 = new Handler();

    final Runnable mUpdateResultsMySpace5 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!out)
            {
                showDialog();
            }

        }
    };
    private void showDialog()
    {

         final CharSequence[] items = {"one", "two"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if(item==0)
                    {


                    }
                    if(item==1)
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the below link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html ---> expand(click) on "Example ProgressDialog with a second thread". This will  solve your problem.

Comment: I think i couldn't explain my question. Actually is it possible to pop up a Dialogue box with 3 buttons(ActivityDialog) ,on Splash Screen where no buttons are clicked??

Comment: Alert Dialog is use to show Dialog where some event has to call the same. If you want to show splash screen as popup window , you need to open Activity class in pop up mode with timers inside it. Hope it wil solve your problem.

Comment: No brother, i have different problem, imagine my splash screen is running and in background gathering some information at the same time i wanted to pop up an Activity Dialogue which says sorry u haven't provided this information would u like to give it now.. so ultimately that dialogue will have some text and 3 buttons viz. positive, negative and say never.

Comment: A solution code has been posted as answer. Hope will solve your problem.